# Request Exchange Web Services 2007/2010 with SOAP+XML over HTTPS in Android

Tags: android, exchangewebservices

I used the following C# code from Microsoft to request EWS 2010 [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc526065.aspx) and it worked. I need the same solution for android.

I tried to use the following code but it does not help

```
    DefaultHttpClient client = new HttpsClient(
                MyActivity.this);

        requestBytes = myXMLStringRequest.getBytes("UTF-8");

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml;utf-8");
        if (requestBytes != null) {
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-length",
                    String.valueOf(requestBytes.length));
            Log.d(TAG, "content length: " + requestBytes.length);
        }

        client.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
                new AuthScope(url, 443),
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials(userName,
                        password));
        Log.d(TAG, "Begin request");
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
        Log.d(TAG, "status Line: " + response.getStatusLine().toString());
```

Here is my xml request

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" 
xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"> 
<soap:Body>
<GetFolder xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"                xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">   
<FolderShape>     
    <t:BaseShape>Default</t:BaseShape>  
</FolderShape>    
<FolderIds>      
    <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="inbox"/>     
    <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="deleteditems"/>  
</FolderIds> 
</GetFolder>
```

I also use custom HttpsClient with keystore.

```
public class HttpsClient extends DefaultHttpClient {
private final Context context;

public HttpsClient(final Context context) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
}

/**
 * The method used to create client connection manager
 */
@Override
protected ClientConnectionManager createClientConnectionManager() {
    final SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
    registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 8080));

    // Register for port 443 our SSLSocketFactory with our keystore
    // to the ConnectionManager
    registry.register(new Scheme("https", newSslSocketFactory(), 8443));
    return new SingleClientConnManager(getParams(), registry);
}

private SSLSocketFactory newSslSocketFactory() {
    try {
        // Get an instance of the Bouncy Castle KeyStore format
        final KeyStore trusted = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
        // Get the raw resource, which contains the keystore with
        // your trusted certificates (root and any intermediate certs)
        final InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.parkgroup_ws_client);
        try {
            // Initialize the keystore with the provided truste
            // certificates
            // Also provide the password of the keystore
            trusted.load(inputStream, "myKeyStorePassword".toCharArray());
        } finally {
            inputStream.close();
        }
        // Pass the keystore to the SSLSocketFactory. The factory is
        // responsible
        // for the verification of the server certificate.
        final SSLSocketFactory ssf = new SSLSocketFactory(trusted);
        // Hostname verification from certificate
        // http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html#d4e506
        ssf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
        return ssf;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("MYTAG", e.getMessage());
        throw new AssertionError(e);
    }
}

@Override
protected HttpParams createHttpParams() {
    final HttpParams httpParams = super.createHttpParams();
    httpParams.setParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, 1000);
    httpParams.setParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.STALE_CONNECTION_CHECK, false);
    return httpParams;
}
```

}

But it always show "*connect timeout*" and does not response anything

Please tell me where is my problem? Any example would be help.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does your server support TLS protocol? There is known bug in android that it fails to connect some servers that does not have TLS enabled.

Comment: Yes, it does. I don't know where is my problem, it always timeout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many thanks to Nikolay Elenkov!

Finally, I found the solution. I follow this link: [Using a Custom Certificate Trust Store on Android](http://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2011/12/using-custom-certificate-trust-store-on.html)

First, I use `DefaultHttpClient` instead of `HttpClient` (the method `createHttpClientWithDefaultSocketFactory()` should be `return DefaultHttpClient`):

```
private DefaultHttpClient createHttpClientWithDefaultSocketFactory(
        KeyStore keyStore, KeyStore trustStore) {
    try {
        SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = SSLSocketFactory
                .getSocketFactory();
        if (keyStore != null && trustStore != null) {
            sslSocketFactory = new SSLSocketFactory(keyStore,
                    KEYSTORE_PASSWORD, trustStore);
        } else if (trustStore != null) {
            sslSocketFactory = new SSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
        }

        return createHttpClient(sslSocketFactory);
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Then I add `CredentialsProvider` for authentication.

```
    DefaultHttpClient client = createHttpClientWithDefaultSocketFactory(
                keyStore, trustStore);
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(SERVER_AUTH_URL);
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "text/xml;utf-8");

        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(builder.toString(), "UTF8");
        se.setContentType("text/xml");
        httpPost.setEntity(se);
        CredentialsProvider credProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();

        credProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(URL,
                443), new UsernamePasswordCredentials(USERNAME, password));

        // This will exclude the NTLM authentication scheme

        client.setCredentialsProvider(credProvider);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
```

Now, it can work well!