# Android HTTPS POST Give Error Not Trusted Server Certificate

Tags: android, https, http-post, ssl-certificate

I have following android POST code.  It works fine for http but fails for HTTPS with Not Trusted Server Certificate exception.  I do not mind self signing or accepting all certificates code (drawback less secure with man-in-the-middle attack).

```
 HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://yourdomain.com/yourskript.xyz");
 List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);

 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("postValue1", "my Value"));
 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("postValue2", "2nd Value"));
 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("postValue3", "3rd Value"));
 post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

 HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(); HttpResponse response =
 client.execute(post); HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

 String responseText = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
```

Any help appreciated here.  I need the certificate portion of the code with submitting POST with postValue1, postValue2, and postValue3 (minimum 3).

Answer (score 0):

You should add the selfsigned certificate to the Android trust store. I've not worked on android self signed cert, but on windows, it will work(mostly)

I've looked up link [here](https://coderwall.com/p/wv6fpq). The author gave good steps to install the self signed cert to android.

More discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851486/how-to-use-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-in-android)

Comment: the issue was my server certificate was expired.  I had to renew it and install it again and it worked fine!  I was under the impression that renewing is just all I had to do.